Generate Classes from JSON Schema using Liquid Studio
Is it possible to generate C# classes from a JSON schema using Liquid Studio?
I had added the lines below to my .csproj file, but in the generated class, I get this error message : Error Error Generating Liquid XML Objects Code. Error No schema files provides.
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="file.json">
    <Generator>LxCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>MyClasses.cs</LastGenOutput>
    <CustomToolNamespace>My.Namespaces</CustomToolNamespace>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>

    .....

  </None>
</ItemGroup>

Thanks for your help.

Sorry no, you would need to use the JSON Schema to XSD Converter and then use the generated XSD.
But the NJsonSchema tool already exists to do what you require.
